# Unity3d Make Object look at touch location

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently making an android game in unity3d. I want to make it so when you touch the screen the cube looks at the touch location and moves toward it. I tried doing a lookat script to the touch position but the rotation is weird and it doesn't move toward the touch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Unity's built in **Navigation System** to make your object move from one point to the other, use a **Ray** to get the point that the player clicked on the screen, and use **Transform.LookAt()** to make your player look at that point.

[Navigation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Navigation.html)

[Raycasting](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html)

[Transform.LookAt](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html)